# Laravel Middleware return user info as null

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I created a middle to prevent a user to not to insert or update anything. I am on Laravel 5.6

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class LimitDemoUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
        if(request()->method() != "GET" && request()->method() != "HEAD" && $userId == 6) {
            abort(403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I registered it to kernel like this ( LimitDemoUser )

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\LimitDemoUser::class,

];
```

But when I dd(Auth::id()); I got null rather than gettin loggedin user id

What am I missing here?

I suppose I don't have o add anything to routemiddleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

];
```

My LoginController is below. Maybe it may help

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/login';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your route code

Comment: I didn't add anything to $routeMiddleware, should I?

Comment: what is your web.php file

Comment: $userId = Auth::user()->id;

Comment: @afsalc for login I only have Auth::routes();

Comment: I added LoginController to the question if it may help. It seems like in the middleware it doesn't recognize that I am logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this page.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/current-user-in-middleware

OP stated

```
i have added the following code in the global middleware and nou is het working 
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

It is dirty but it worked. I don't think that this is the best practice but it solved the problem. Since we found the problem, from here can someone suggest a decent solution?

Comment: This is not working for Laravel 5.8.
I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `\App\Http\Middleware\LimitDemoUser::class` to the end of `web` middleware group array.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...,
        \App\Http\Middleware\LimitDemoUser::class,
     ]
];
```

Comment: Best answer for me: resolved my very similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your loginController should be as below:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to get the user id, you should the user class.

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    // The user is logged in...
    Auth::user()->id;
}
else
{
    echo "You are not logged in";
}
```

Comment: I got Trying to get property of non-object error dd (Auth::user() ) returns null as well

Comment: yes it says you are not logged in but I am logged in :) Should I state something to the middleware that I am logged in?

Comment: @SNaRe, are you sure you are logged in?

Comment: yes because when I delete else I got to my logged in page

Comment: Umm! your problem is with your logging controller

Comment: Should I add to Auth::routes(); somehow?

Comment: Please attach your loginController with your question

Comment: Added Gulmuhammad Akbari

Comment: There is no any function to authenticate the user in your loginController

Comment: This is Laravel's default Auth and I can authorize users with this. But why I need something like Authenticate right now?

Comment: For more how to use Laravel Authentication, please go to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your web.php to

```
Route::middleware(['limitdemouser'])->group(function () {
  Auth::routes();
});
```

and your $routeMiddleware is

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'limitdemouser' => \App\Http\Middleware\LimitDemoUser::class,
];
```

Let me know if not works

Comment: I was just trying this before you wrote this. But it doesn't work as well.